# Selenium Webdriver Print to PDF using Preference File - Not Working

Tags: pdf, selenium-webdriver, printing, chromium

My task is to convert a HTML file to a 1 page PDF file.

My Python program opens a HTML file and set's Chromium  page size options to 8.5 x 46 13/16  ("height_microns": 1189000 &  "width_microns": 215900).  I hardcoded pdf page size for testing; the page size parameters will be passed in.

I updated the Chrome "{user}/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Preferences" file  and added a new "Z0" definition.

Run program to print to PDF.

- The resulting file defaults letter size ( 8.5 x 11 ).
- The "Preference" file gets re-created without my "Z0" entry.
- The Chromium.log file shows my "Z0" definitions' height and width values.

## Preference File - Manually entered

{"height_microns":1189000,"name":"ISO_Z0","width_microns":215900,"custom_display_name":"Z0"}

## Python Code

```
    # Translation 
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

    settings = {
                "recentDestinations": [{
                    "id": "Save as PDF",
                    "origin": "local",
                    "account": ""
                }],
                "selectedDestinationId": "Save as PDF",
                "version": 2,
                "isHeaderFooterEnabled": False,
                "mediaSize": {
                    "height_microns": 1189000,
                    "name": "ISO_Z0",
                    "width_microns": 215900,
                    "custom_display_name":  "Z0",
                    "is_default": True,
                    "vendor_id": "1120"
                },
                "marginsType": 1,
                "isCssBackgroundEnabled": True
            }        


    prefs = {
        'printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState': json.dumps(settings),
        'savefile.default_directory': outputDir,
        "printing.default_destination_selection_rules": {
        "kind": "local",
        "namePattern": "Save as PDF"
        }
    }        

    chrome_options.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)


    # Enable logging
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(GBL_CHROME_WEBDRIVER, options=chrome_options, service_args=["--verbose", r"--log-path=c:\dev\temp\chromedriver.log"])

    # driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromeDriverDir, options=chrome_options)
    htmlFileName = os.path.join(inputDir, HtmlFN)
    driver.get(f'file://{htmlFileName}')
    # driver.get(f'file://{os.path.join(inputDir, HtmlFN)}')
    time.sleep(4)
    driver.execute_script('window.print();')
    driver.close()
```

Also: Where is there documentation for these Chromium options.  What is "version : 2" ?

Help is appreciated.  Thx

Comment: I still need a solution to the above.

I found a post with a manual workaround provided in the 1st answer in this link.   Can someone post code how to Selenium automate these steps in Python?

https://superuser.com/questions/867631/how-can-i-save-a-web-page-as-single-page-pdf

Comment: More testing - does not work.  . SuperUser method  Print long html  using option "Adobe PDF" prints to multiple pages.